# How to call for a method from OnCreate with menu item?

Tags: android, menuitem

I'm building an app with option to load a work space from remote (via ADB), using this code in `OnCreate`:

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent ( ).getExtras ( );
if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("workspace"))
{
    String param = extras.getString("workspace");
    WSmethods.loadWorkspace(param); //work space methods class
}
```

This work space effect *save* menu item, therefore my workspace constractor contain this menu item, like this:

```
public workspaceMethods(MyActivity myActivity, MenuItem saveItem)
```

but, in order to receive `MenuItem` I have to wait for `onCreateOptionsMenu` method that called after `OnCreate`

Therefore, I found myself in a tangle: On the one hand I have to call my work space methods in OnCreate (in order to receive commands from ADB) and on the other hand I have to receive my menu item that initialize after OnCreate called.

Bottom line, the question: How can I call for method from OnCreate with a menu item? (to be more accurate, in my case the question is how to initialize class variable with menu item in OnCreate method?)

**EDIT** I initialize `WSmethods` like this (in onCreateOptionsMenu):

```
WSmethods = new workspaceMethods(this, menu.findItem(R.id.action_save));
```

Comment: You could try moving the `loadWorkspace` method to `onStart`.

Comment: Thanks Roshan, but `onStart` calling before `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: What about moving it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` itself? Seems there are varying results on when `onCreateOptionsMenu` actually gets called.

Comment: @Roshan, that's exactly Denis Vasilenko answer below :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all access to intent extras even from `onCreateOptionsMenu`. So just call your method from it - after inflating your menu.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I'm just going to restart as I was under the impression you were implementing the fragment framework.

try this:

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
    super .onPostCreate(savedInstance);
    WSmethods = new workspaceMethods(this, menu.findItem(R.id.action_save));
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_save:
             WSmethods = new workspaceMethods(Activity.this, item);
             //do actions associated with method
              break;
             //other switch cases
         default:
           //implement a default action
              break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, but I not understand how to beat the problem (if it possible..)